# Dynamic Instantaition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I looked at other online examples, but they didn't work.

So...

I am trying to implement the classic "Decorator Pattern" from 'Head First' in JavaScript...and I am REALLY close.

**GIVEN THE FOLLOWING "CLASSES":**

```
// "CLASSES": BEVERAGES
function DarkRoast(){
    this.cost = 1.00;
    this.description = "Dark Roast";
};

// DECORATORS: CONDIMENTS
function Milk(beverage){
    var instance = beverage;
    beverage.cost = function(){
        return instance.cost + 0.25;
    };
    beverage.description = functionn(){
        return instance.description + ', Milk';
    };
};
```

**QUESTION: How can I instantiate "Milk" dynamically from the following function?**

```
function appendCondiment(className, beverage) {
    /* Needs to do this, but dynamically:
        var instance = new Milk(beverage); */

    // This fails (of course)
    var instance = new window[className].call(beverage);
}
```

Comment: Your classes are global functions? That's a bad idea... the use of global variables should be minimized. Define a `MYAPP.classes` namespace, and then `var Milk = MYAPP.classes["Milk"]`...

Comment: You are overwriting the `.cost` numeric property with a `.cost` method. (Same goes for `.description`) You can't have two properties of the same name on the same object.

Comment: `new` is pointless for `Milk`. It modifies `beverage` instead of `this`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas  In the final code I AM doing that.  You are solving a question that has not been asked.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO I am merely commenting on the code that is in your question.

Comment: @pimvdb  I'm not sure the example is "pointless" as this is EXACTLY the sample put forth by Addy Osmoni (a famous JavaScript author) in the following book: http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#decoratorpatternjavascript

Comment: He's not calling decorators with `new`. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
var instance = new window[className](beverage);
```

Comment: While, this did instantiate the instance.  Calling COST on beverage fails.  So this solution will not work.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO It fails because your `.cost` method overwrote the `.cost` numeric property. You can't have two properties of the same name on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var DarkRoast = function () {
    this.cost = 1.00;
    this.description = 'Dark Roast';
};

var condiments = {
    milk: {
        cost: 0.25;
        description: 'Milk'
    },
    cream: {
        cost: 0.3,
        description: 'Cream'
    }
};

var appendCondiment = function ( condimentName, beverage ) {
    var condiment = condiments[ condimentName ];
    beverage.cost += condiment.cost;
    beverage.description += ', ' + condiment.description;
};
```

Usage:

```
var bev = new DarkRoast();
appendCondiment( 'milk', bev );

bev.cost // 1.25
bev.description // 'Dark Roast, Milk'
```

---

Btw, consider having `DarkRoast` inherit from a `Beverage` class, and then defining a `appendCondiment` method to `Beverage.prototype`. Then you would be able to write this:

```
var bev = new DarkRoast();
bev.appendCondiment( 'milk' );
```

which is more readable.

Comment: Why stop there? Seems to me "dark roast" should be an attribute of a Beverage "class", so `var bev = new Beverage('dark roast')` and so on.